# How to create a log-based alert using the Monitoring API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

On the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts#lba-api) it say's there is a link for an example of creating a log-based alert using the Monitoring API but there's only an example how to create it using the UI.

I am having trouble building a new alertPolicy using the Java Monitoring API because there does not seem to be a Condition builder for Log-based alerts (using the Log query filter). I don't think I should be using the Absent, Threshold, or MonitoringQueryLanguage options. How can I build the correct condition?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ashish pointed out, this is not currently available in the client library. Hopefully it will be added soon but for the time being for anyone who wants to add a log based alert condition (conditionMatchedLog) using the Java Client library, this is what the code looks like.

```
  public static UnknownFieldSet createConditionMatchedLog(String filter) {
    // filter = "\nseverity = \"NOTICE\""; example filter

    UnknownFieldSet.Field logMatchString =
            UnknownFieldSet.Field.newBuilder()
                    .addLengthDelimited(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(filter))
                    .build();

    UnknownFieldSet logMatchFilter =
            UnknownFieldSet.newBuilder()
                    .addField(1, logMatchString)
                    .build();

    UnknownFieldSet.Field logMatchFilterCombine =
            UnknownFieldSet.Field.newBuilder()
                    .addLengthDelimited(logMatchFilter.toByteString())
                    .build();

    UnknownFieldSet logMatchCondition =
            UnknownFieldSet.newBuilder()
                    .addField(20, logMatchFilterCombine)
                    .build();

    return logMatchCondition;
  }
```

When constructing the actual Alert, you also need to define the Alert Strategy.

```
public static UnknownFieldSet createAlertStrategyFieldSet(long periodTime) {
    //Making the alertStrategy field since you need those for log based alert policies
    UnknownFieldSet.Field period =
            UnknownFieldSet.Field.newBuilder()
                    .addVarint(periodTime) //must be an long
                    .build();

    UnknownFieldSet periodSet =
            UnknownFieldSet.newBuilder()
                    .addField(1, period)
                    .build();

    UnknownFieldSet.Field periodSetField =
            UnknownFieldSet.Field.newBuilder()
                    .addLengthDelimited(periodSet.toByteString())
                    .build();

    UnknownFieldSet periodSetFieldUp =
            UnknownFieldSet.newBuilder()
                    .addField(1, periodSetField)
                    .build();

    UnknownFieldSet.Field periodSetField2 =
            UnknownFieldSet.Field.newBuilder()
                    .addLengthDelimited(periodSetFieldUp.toByteString())
                    .build();

    UnknownFieldSet periodSetFieldUp2 =
            UnknownFieldSet.newBuilder()
                    .addField(1, periodSetField2)
                    .build();

    UnknownFieldSet.Field periodSetField3 =
            UnknownFieldSet.Field.newBuilder()
                    .addLengthDelimited(periodSetFieldUp2.toByteString())
                    .build();


    UnknownFieldSet AlertStrategy =
            UnknownFieldSet.newBuilder()
                    .addField(21, periodSetField3)
                    .build();
    return AlertStrategy;
  }
```

Putting it together

```
UnknownFieldSet conditionMatchedLog = createConditionMatchedLog(filter);

// Construct Condition object
AlertPolicy.Condition alertPolicyCondition =
        AlertPolicy.Condition.newBuilder()
                .setDisplayName(med.getConditions().get(index).getDisplayName())
                .setUnknownFields(conditionMatchedLog)
                .build();

//Making the alertStrategy field since you need those for log based alert policies
UnknownFieldSet alertStrategy = createAlertStrategyFieldSet(convertTimePeriodFromString(med.getAlertStrategy().getNotificationRateLimit().getPeriod()));

// Build the log based alert policy
AlertPolicy alertPolicy =
        AlertPolicy.newBuilder()
                .setDisplayName(med.getDisplayName())
                .addConditions(alertPolicyCondition)
                .setCombiner(AlertPolicy.ConditionCombinerType.OR)
                .setEnabled(BoolValue.newBuilder().setValue(true).build())
                .setUnknownFields(alertStrategy)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

- The three condition types MetricAbsence, MetricThreshold and MonitoringQueryLanguageCondition are [Conditions for metric-based alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/policies-in-api#metric-polices). Since we want to create a log based alert policy, according to the [Condition for log-based alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/policies-in-api#log-polices), the condition type must be "**LogMatch**".
- [AlertPolicy.Condition.Builder](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-monitoring/latest/com/google/monitoring/v3/AlertPolicy.Condition.Builder.html) class has methods to set condition with metric-based alerting condition types but not with log-based condition type i.e., LogMatch. The class "AlertPolicy.Condition.Builder" doesn't seem to have a method to do so. Note that the log-based alert is **pre-GA (Preview) feature per public doc**. So various client libraries may not support this yet.
- Although, when creating a new Alert Policy using [projects.alertPolicies.create](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies/create?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2Fsample-id%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22conditions%22%3A%5B%7B%22conditionMatchedLog%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D), we can add a condition of type "conditionMatchedLog".
- So, it is recommended to use [UI](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts#lba-definition) or above API, but not the client library until it supports the condition.

Comment: That is as I had also seen, so thanks for confirming. I did code a version that let's me do log based alerts using the API by going in and working directly with the protobuf. I hope Google is able to add this feature in the future.